# Quickly compute Structural Similarity Index for a large number of images

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, image-processing

I have a large amount of binary images stored as numpy arrays in a dataframe column. All of these arrays are of the same shape (`224, 224`) and all contain the same data type (`np.uint8`).  This is an example of a binary image I use:

[image: A four sided object]

Next, I use `df.sample` to fetch a random entry from the dataframe, this simulates a user input image, for example:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 255 255 255]]
```

My next task is to compute a new dataframe column with the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) between the input image (sample) and **all** other images in the dataframe. I have tried two packages that implement SSIM so far:

```
from image_similarity_measures.quality_metrics import ssim
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim_2
import timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sample= df['Images'].sample(n=1).values[0]

# Image Similarity Measures Package
start = timeit.default_timer()
df['Similarity_1'] = df['Images'].apply(lambda x: ssim(x, sample))
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Similarity Measures: ', stop - start)

# Skimage
start = timeit.default_timer()
df['Similarity_2'] = df['Images'].apply(lambda x: ssim_2(x, sample))
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Skimage: ', stop - start)
```

For a set of 1000 images, my runtimes are as follows:

```
Similarity Measures: 21.4252301
Skimage: 3.3435048999999992
```

These times are incredibly slow given that I need to compare upwards of 70.000 images in as little time as possible. I had previously used an approach with `sklearn`'s cosine similarity metric, which works pairwise, and was able to compute similarity values in a fraction of a second, but the values are far less accurate in comparison to SSIM.

How can I improve my code's speed? Are there other, more efficient ways to compare binary images?

Comment: First, I won't use pandas and certainly not .apply since it's quite inefficient. Storing your data by key in a dict or hashmap will be more efficient. 

If speed is really an issue, using numba or some cython will be key here

Comment: I took some time to understand the basics of numba and realized it does not work well with pandas DataFrames or Python dicts. I am currently trying multiprocessing but the results so far aren't promising. I might have to switch back to more efficient similarity metrics.

Comment: That's why I mentioned not using pandas, not really amazing if performance is an issue. But quite powerful nonetheless

Comment: Have you considered multiprocessing?

Comment: As I mentioned in my response to @Zelemist, multiprocessing was tested. I had improvements, but not nearly significant enough.
I ended up with downscaling image resolution to (28, 28), utilizing a PCA Based Approach for determining image orientation, and computing the pixel-wise similarity for a performance boost of over 560x without losing too much information.